# SQL: a symbol name was expected

Tags: mysql

Trying to implement this in to a DB, everything else like it has worked so far.

```
create table participation (
    team_id int(11) not null,
    driver_id int(11) not null,
    race_id int(11) not null,
    points_earned int(11),
constraint part_pk primary key (team_id, driver_id, race_id),
constraint part_fk foreign key (team_id) references team (team_id) ON update cascade,
constraint part_fktwo foreign key (driver_id) references driver (driver_id) ON update cascade,
constraint part_fkthree foreign key (race_id) references race (race_id) ON update cascade,
)
engine=innodb;
```

Getting an error at the last parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra comma at the end of your query (the last foreign key constraint):

```
create table participation (
    team_id int(11) not null,
    driver_id int(11) not null,
    race_id int(11) not null,
    points_earned int(11),
    constraint part_pk primary key (team_id, driver_id, race_id),
    constraint part_fk foreign key (team_id) references team (team_id) ON update cascade,
    constraint part_fktwo foreign key (driver_id) references driver (driver_id) ON update cascade,
    constraint part_fkthree foreign key (race_id) references race (race_id) ON update cascade
)
engine=innodb;
```